# Exclude IPod from play count in iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod

Is there a way for avoiding the update to my play counts when I sync my iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [forum post](http://ask.metafilter.com/21960/How-do-I-combine-the-play-count-of-iTunes-and-my-iPod#353547) from 2005 suggests that "Manually manage music and videos" prevents play counts from syncing, but this may have changed in the last 6-7 years. This option is found on the Summary page when the iPod is selected in iTunes.

Comment: Thank Timothy, however that will mean that I have to synchronize the music manually... I was looking for a better solution :)

Comment: There's also a way to toggle play count updates via Home Sharing, but that's not how the music is being played. I'm fairly certain there isn't a *native* way to do it, though there may well be some kind of third-party app to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I had an iPod in my car which I always forgot to turn off...son now I have some song with 900 plays :)

Comment: Oh, well if it's just one song, right-click it and select "Reset Plays."

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this. Play counts and ratings don't update to iTunes if you select to manually manage music and videos on your iOS device.

In iTunes 10.6.3, there's no option to ignore play counts and ratings when you sync with certain iOS devices.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the other answer and should definitely include an upvote.